# Connected unbounded sets $S\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $x\mapsto ||x||^t$ is uniformly continuous on $S$?

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-geometry, parametric, uniform-continuity

Spending the night perusing my old answers, and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351850/11619) left me wondering about the following.

Let's equip $\Bbb{R}^n$ with the usual Euclidean metric, and let us consider the map $N_t:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$, $N_t(\vec{x})=||\vec{x}||^t$. The parameter $t$ is a positive constant, and the question I want to ask is:

> For which pairs $(n,t)$ does there exist an unbounded path-connected set $S\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ such that the restriction $N_t\vert_S$ is uniformly continuous?

"Clearly" with $n=1$ we need $t\le1$. Path-connected + unbounded leaves no wiggle room for choice of $S$. The answers to the linked question give sets such that $N_2\vert_S$ is uniformly continuous, but those sets are not connected - hence this question.

With $n\ge2$ the game is more interesting. I'm thinking of a $S$ as a path slowly spiralling outwards. With $n=2$ something like $S$ = Archimedean spiral, with the distance from the origin growing at the constant rate of one unit per each full revolution, looks good for showing that all $t\le2$ are ok. Here the length of the path in the $n$th loop is about $2\pi n$ meaning that if $\vec{x}$ moves by $<\delta$ the distance from the origin will change by approximately a constant times $\delta/n$. In that case $N_2(\vec{x})$ will grow from $n^2$
to $(n+K\delta/n)^2\approx n^2+2K\delta$, which is ok, just barely, for the purposes of uniform continuity.

[image]

It doesn't look nearly as promising for $t>2$. If we are spiralling out any slower, then further out the distance between consecutive rounds of the spiral will tend to zero. Looks like that makes uniform continuity an unrealistic goal, and

> The argument by user147263 from the comments under the question shows that the exponent $t$ cannot exceed the dimension of the ambient space.

I haven't really thought about $n\ge3$. We can use the extra wiggle room by spending more time at about the same distance, like "nearly cover" the sphere at radius $n$ while gradually moving on to the sphere of radius $n+1$ and repeating ever after. But I don't know any good 3D-spirals, not forgetting $n$D.

Any thoughts? Ideas? Suitable higher dimensional spirals? Known work?

Comment: If this is too broad in general, I think the 3D case is interesting enough. Of course, if I'm wrong about 2D, that is even more interesting!

Comment: For $t>n$ there is no such set: For all sufficiently large $k$ the set $S$ must contain a point $x_k$ with $\|x_k\|=k^{1/t}$, by  connectedness. Since $N_t(x_k)=k$, the  points $x_k$ must be uniformly separated: there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\|x_k-x_j\|\ge \delta$ for all $k\ne j$.

For large $R$, the ball $B(0,R)$ contains over $R^{ t}/2$ points $x_k$. Since the balls $B(x_k,\delta/2)$ are disjoint, it follows that 
$R^n \ge (R^t/2) (\delta/2)^n$,
which yields a contradiction when $R$ is large enough.

Comment: Well argued, @Fundamental! That result probably won't surprise anyone, but it gives a good starting point. If you can find the time do consider posting it as an answer as well.

Comment: Do you want uniform continuity with respect to the path metric or with respect to the induced Euclidean metric? The Archimedean spiral only works for the first one.

Comment: @Joonas: I was thinking about the metric induced by the Euclidean metric of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Why wouldn't the Archimedean spiral work with that metric?

Comment: You do get continuity, but you don't get a Lipschitz estimate. (I will edit my answer.) The distance from a point on the spiral to the radially next point on it is a constant $\delta r$. The difference between $N_2$ at these two points is $(r+\delta r)^2-r^2=2r\delta r+(\delta r)^2$ grows without bounds.

Comment: @Joonas, that only implies that to any $\epsilon>0$ the corresponding $\delta$ must be less than that global constant $\delta r$. The radially next point is then far enough not to violate uniform continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is more of a "sketch proof" at the moment.)

The pairs are exactly $(t,n)$ with $t\leq n.$ The necessity was posted in a comment which I'll quote here:

> For $t>n$ there is no such set: For all sufficiently large $k$ the set $S$ must contain a point $x_k$ with $\|x_k\|=k^{1/t},$ by connectedness. Since $N_t(x_k)=k,$ the points $x_k$ must be uniformly separated: there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\|x_k−x_j\|\geq\delta$ for all $k\neq j.$ For large $R,$ the ball $B(0,R)$ contains over $R^t/2$ points $x_k.$ Since the balls $B(x_k,\delta/2)$ are disjoint, it follows that $R_n\geq(R^t/2)(\delta/2)^n,$ which yields a contradiction when $R$ is large enough. – **user147263**

For $t=n$ there's no contradiction, but the balls $B(x_k,\delta/2)$ end up covering a positive proportion of $B(0,R).$ So the set isn't quite space-filling, but close: a $\delta/2$-neighborhood of the set covers a positive fraction of the space.

I'll just consider the $t=n$ case, because I want to reuse the letter $t.$
I'll assume $n\geq 2.$ (Perhaps interestingly, for $n\geq 3$ the construction can take place inside any cone with non-empty interior, in particular in $\mathbb R_{>0}\times \mathbb R^{n-1},$ whereas for $n=2$ unless I'm mistaken there is no unbounded connected subset of the upper half plane $\mathbb R_{>0}\times\mathbb R$ on which $N_2$ is continuous.)

Let $\mathbb T$ denote the metric space $\mathbb R/\mathbb 2\pi Z$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\min_{n\in\mathbb Z}|x+2\pi n-y|.$
There is a bilipschitz embedding $\phi$ of $\mathbb T\times [0,1]^{n-2}$ into the sphere $S^{n-1}.$ For $n=2$ this is just embedding a circle in a circle; for $n>2$ embed $\mathbb T\times [0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ as an annulus, pass through the other coordinates to get an embedding $\mathbb T\times [0,1]^{n-2}\to\mathbb R^{n-1},$ then use stereographic projection $\mathbb R^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}.$

Start with the curve $\gamma(t)=(t,0,\dots,0)$ for $t>1$ - we'll modify this. For each odd integer $m>3,$ in the segment $m<t<m+1,$ the curve lives in a $(n-1)$-dimensional cube $[m,m+1]\times [0,1]^{n-2}.$ We can think of this as being a path through an $(n-1)$-dimensional $m\times m\times \dots\times m$ grid graph, with step size $1/(m-1),$ where the path starts in one corner and exits at another.
Replace the curve within this cube by a Hamiltonian path with the same start and end - this is quite easy to construct. Smooth the corners. The important feature is that there are no significant "short cuts" smaller than $\Theta(1/m)$; specifically, for any two points at Euclidean distance $L<1/2m$ the arc length of the curve between these points is at most $L/2.$

Do the modification for each odd $m>3.$ Let $s(t)$ denote the following modified arc length:
$$s(t)=\int_1^t \tau|\gamma'(\tau)|\;d\tau.$$

Then $s(t)$ increases by $\Theta(m^{n-1})$ during $m<t<m+2,$ which gives $s(t)=\Theta(t^n).$ Set $S_n=\{s(t)^{1/n}\phi(\gamma(t))\mid t>1\}.$ It should be clear that $S_n$ is unbounded and path-connected. I claim that $N_n$ is uniformly continuous on $S_n,$ in fact satisfying a kind of Lipschitz property on small scales.
Consider $3<t<t'.$ We want to show $$|s(t)-s(t')|\leq C\|s(t)^{1/n}\phi(\gamma(t))-s(t')^{1/n}\phi(\gamma(t'))\|\tag{*}$$
for some large constant $C,$ whenever the right-hand-side is smaller than some small constant $c>0.$

The nice way for the right-hand-side to be small is when $|t-t'|<2$ and the quantity $L=|\gamma(t)-\gamma(t')|$ is at most $1/4t.$ Then because there are no "short cuts" we must have $|s(t)-s(t')|<2Lt.$
Using $s(t)^{1/n}=\Theta(t),$ the right-hand-side of (*) is $\Theta(Lt),$ which is perfect.

We need to rule out the possibility that the right-hand-side is small after looping around $\mathbb T$ a number of times. But this would only occur if $|t-t'|>2,$ which means $|s(t)-s(t')|>\Theta(t^{n-1}),$ which makes $|s(t)^{1/n}-s(t')^{1/n}|>\Theta(1).$ So the right-hand-side cannot be small this way.

Comment: Using a cone shaped region only is a nice idea, and seems to get around at least some of the difficulties I had when trying to "fill" the entire space. I would imagine it being easier to avoid the "shortcuts if the Hamiltonian paths exits near the starting corner - recalling that along that path we will also have gradually "moved out" to the next layer. May be I didn't get all your ideas? Anyway, this is better than what I have been trying.

Comment: Due to some in-person advertisements, I was gonna come write an answer, but this seems to be the same construction I had in mind. I'll just upvote then.

Comment: Yup. @Ville, this was eerily close to your suggestion that for a moment I thought I had found your alter ego here.

Comment: Anyway the remaining doubt I have is how to make it sure that the late stage of the Hamiltonian path at layer $m$ does not too close to the early parts of the Hamiltonian path at layer $m+1$. I think we need a constant fraction (possible depending on the dimension) of those two paths not to be close to each other. An explicit construction would be nice. Anyway, Dap, you said this is just a sketch, and it is good at that. I believe it can be made to work, but my $nD$-imagination is a bit lacking to see it all.

Comment: Oh, I see, that indeed needs some additional argument.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem if they are close, they are radially separated by a constant distance (I didn't read the last calculations, probably I should leave answering to @Dap who actually did some math).

Comment: Erm, ok, it needs some additional argument. I will now shut up.

Comment: At the risk of breaking my promise: we're just using a cone. We could use two that intersect in a single radial line, and have every second Hamiltonian path in another cone.

Comment: That's an elegant solution @Ville. Do consider posting it as an answer as well. No rush.

Answer (score 6):

Let $r:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ and $\omega:(0,\infty)\to S^{n-1}$ be smooth smooth functions that define a curve $\gamma$ by $\gamma(s)=r(s)\omega(s)$ in spherical coordinates.
I want to choose $S=\gamma((0,\infty))$, so I need to assume $r(s)\to\infty$ as $s\to\infty$.
I will also assume $r$ to be increasing and $t$ to be positive.

Let $f(x)=\|x\|^t$.
To ensure uniform continuity, I want the local Lipschitz constant of $f|_S$ at $\gamma(s)$,
$$
L(s)=\frac{\frac{d}{ds}f(\gamma(s))}{\|\dot\gamma(s)\|},
$$
to be uniformly bounded.
We have
$$
\frac{d}{ds}f(\gamma(s))
=
tr^{t-1}\dot r
$$
and
$$
\|\dot\gamma(s)\|^2
=
\|\dot r\omega+r\dot\omega\|^2
=
\dot r^2+r^2\|\dot\omega\|^2.
$$
For the last equation, note that $2\omega\cdot\dot\omega=\frac{d}{ds}\|\omega\|^2=0$.
Thus
$$
L(s)^2
=
t^2\frac{r^{2(t-1)}\dot r^2}{\dot r^2+r^2\|\dot\omega\|^2}
=
t^2\frac{r^{2(t-1)}}{1+(\|\dot\omega\|/\dot\ell)^2},
$$
where $\ell=\log(r)$.

For the Archimedean spiral $r=\omega=s$ we get $L(s)^2=t^2s^{2(t-1)}/(1+s^2)$, which stays bounded if and only if $t\leq2$.
This was expected.

A uniform bound on $L(s)$ does not suffice for uniform continuity; if the "spiral" $S$ is too tight, $f|_S$ is not uniformly continuous.
To make this issue easier to handle, let me assume that $\omega$ is periodic with some period $p>0$.
I'm not sure if a periodic choice is optimal, but I have a vague feeling that an "optimal spiral" is periodic enough for the argument to work.

Note that if you want uniform continuity with respect to the path metric, bounding $L(s)$ is enough.
If you want it w.r.t. the induced Euclidean metric, it is not.

Suppose we want Hölder continuity with exponent $\alpha\in(0,1]$.
Then we get the requirement that
$$
r(s+p)^t-r(s)^t\lesssim (r(s+p)-r(s))^\alpha.
$$
(I don't want to keep track of multiplicative constants anymore, and I will assume $r$ to be so nice that I can make some approximations.)
The function $r$ cannot grow too fast if we want $L(s)$ to remain bounded, so
$$
r(s+p)^t-r(s)^t\approx t(r(s+p)-r(s))r(s)^{t-1}
$$
should be a reasonable approximation.
This combined with the above estimate gives
$$
(r(s+p)-r(s))^{1-\alpha}r(s)^{t-1}\lesssim 1.
$$
Approximating $r(s+p)-r(s)\approx p\dot r(s)$, we get
$$
\dot r(s)^{1-\alpha}r(s)^{t-1}\lesssim 1.
$$
This condition is not necessary for uniform continuity if $r(s+p)-r(s)$ has a uniform lower bound.

To make $L(s)$ bounded we should have
$$
r^{2(t-1)}
\lesssim
(\|\dot\omega\|/\dot\ell)^2.
$$
If we choose the parametrization so that $\|\dot\omega\|$ is constant, we end up with two requirements (if $r(s+p)-r(s)\to0$ as $r\to\infty$):

1. $\dot r^{1-\alpha}r^{t-1}\lesssim1$,
2. $\dot r r^{t-2}\lesssim1$.

Assuming $\alpha<1$ (which is not very restrictive), the first condition can be rewritten as $\dot r r^{(t-1)/(1-\alpha)}\lesssim1$.
The condition then becomes
$$
\dot r r^{\max\{(t-1)/(1-\alpha),t-2\}}\lesssim1.
$$
If the spiral tightens up so that $r(s+p)-r(s)\to0$ as $r\to\infty$, the modulus of continuity of $N_t|_S$ should be as bad as that of $N_t$ in all of $\mathbb R^n$ (although this does not somehow show up in the calculation above).

It seems that the most promising way to go is to demand that $r(s+p)-r(s)\gtrsim1$ and $\dot r r^{t-2}\lesssim1$.

This answer is not conclusive, though...

Comment: The next loop of the Archimedean spiral is about $2\pi r$ in length, so we have $dr/ds\approx \delta r/(2\pi r)$, and thus $d(r^2)/ds\approx \delta r/\pi$, which is a constant. Here $s$ is the natural parameter on the spiral. The metric on the set $S$ is supposed to be the one induced from the Euclidean one.

Comment: You are right, I realized myself that the Archimedean spiral works since it doesn't tighten. My answer does not give a solid conclusion, but it gives some possibilities and conclusions. It somehow seems that the result doesn't depend on the dimension, but I can't be sure. Thanks for pointing out my mistakes!

Comment: No worries! Have you any ideas for a construction in higher dimensions?

Comment: No, not really. I don't see how higher dimensions would help, although it doesn't seem impossible, either. The amount of time you can move on $S^n$ with unit speed before coming close to an earlier point grows as $n$ grows, but stays fixed for any fixed $n$. By the way, do you know of a construction in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space? It might be useful to look at the extreme case $n=\infty$, so to speak.

Comment: Hmm. Wasn't one of the reasons why the Archimedean spiral works that the time spent at distance $r$ grows linearly with $r$. Here "time" is the natural parameter, i.e. the arc length. I am hoping that in 3D, because the area of a sphere grows as $4\pi r^2$, the time spent at distance $r$ could also grow like $O(r^2)$ or, failing that, at least be more than linear. Rafflesia's comment explains that we always have $t\le n$, so we cannot do better than that.

Comment: It depends on the time parameter you choose, but yes, with arc length it grows linearly. (And maybe my idea of periodic $\omega$ is not a good one.) I now see your idea more clearly, but I still see an obstruction: Constructing the curve $S$ is similar to making a ball of yarn. In dimension two you can make a new layer so that the yarn doesn't cross itself before the layer is complete. This does not seem so easy on $S^n$, $n\geq2$, since the topology is so different, but might still be possible.

Comment: That! Is a serious obstruction! We may try something like rolling the yarn only on the region with latitude bounded away from the poles. But turning to the next layer will then become difficult. May be 4D?